# Path Fill Not Filling the Path

Tags: wpf, drawing

I am new to creating svg/wpf style images, but I really want the scalability of a vector based image when creating icons and buttons in my WPF application. As I am not the greatest with Expression Blend/Design/Xaml paths...I found an image (peice of toast), traced it in inkscape to get the coordinate data, and put the data into a path in wpf.

It worked great, but I only have a stroke and can't figure out how to get the fill to actually fill work. The exact path is below...I am not sure if the path is not connected, or if I am doing something wrong.

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong and how to get the fill to work (Maybe i should be using path geometry??)?

```
<Path x:Name="path" 
            Data="m 1019.9016,2413.6161 c -9.6791,-1.5608 -26.77911,-5.1262 -38,-7.9231 -25.2557,-6.2951 -80.95781,-21.994 -82.65127,-23.2941 -0.68732,-0.5277 -8.28932,-10.6343 -16.89333,-22.4591 l -15.64366,-21.4997 -3.89082,-15.1281 -3.89082,-15.1282 -2.09894,-73.5 -2.09893,-73.5 4.09893,-20.2722 4.09894,-20.2721 9.87843,-17.7279 9.87843,-17.7278 3.65882,-16.5 c 2.01235,-9.075 3.65742,-17.5681 3.65572,-18.8735 -0.002,-1.3053 -6.0781,-25.7947 -13.5031,-54.4208 l -13.5,-52.0473 0,-31.3997 0,-31.3997 -5.96265,-47.6795 c -3.27946,-26.2237 -8.24131,-66.5795 -11.02633,-89.6795 -2.78502,-23.1 -9.15772,-74.85 -14.16156,-115 l -9.09788,-73 2.02018,-77.5 2.02019,-77.5 16.07411,-64 c 14.80469,-58.9457 16.85389,-66.1718 25.94821,-91.5 5.43075,-15.125 13.39094,-38.075 17.6893,-51 4.29836,-12.925 12.41469,-34.56 18.03628,-48.0777 l 10.22107,-24.5776 36.27346,-54.4224 c 19.9504,-29.9323 40.51274,-60.3703 45.69408,-67.64013 l 9.42064,-13.2178 -15.64565,-17.5131 -15.64562,-17.51298 -10.30857,-30.76914 C 958.87955,903.02992 947.21154,871.58319 938.62035,850.07133 930.02916,828.55946 923,810.08374 923,809.01417 c 0,-1.06958 1.80538,-15.19396 4.01195,-31.38752 2.93085,-21.50885 5.48318,-35.64067 9.47164,-52.44284 3.00283,-12.65 6.612,-28.4 8.02039,-35 1.40838,-6.6 4.96838,-21 7.91111,-32 2.94272,-11 7.99067,-30.73137 11.21766,-43.8475 l 5.86725,-23.8475 3.75,0.50234 c 4.32955,0.57998 4.43628,0.33053 1.74626,-4.08151 -2.12927,-3.49232 -2.58385,-6.74465 -1.0732,-7.67828 0.50769,-0.31377 1.21844,-1.91532 1.57946,-3.55902 0.36101,-1.64369 1.03488,-2.98853 1.49748,-2.98853 0.4626,0 1.13639,-1.34452 1.49732,-2.98781 0.36093,-1.6433 1.74669,-3.84557 3.07946,-4.89392 1.33277,-1.04836 2.42322,-2.15629 2.42322,-2.46206 0,-0.30577 1.35,-2.55627 3,-5.0011 1.65,-2.44484 3,-4.78127 3,-5.19207 0,-0.4108 1.72095,-3.49554 3.82434,-6.85498 2.10339,-3.35943 4.11427,-6.89556 4.46862,-7.85806 0.35435,-0.9625 1.10839,-1.75 1.67566,-1.75 0.56728,0 1.03138,-0.675 1.03138,-1.5 0,-0.825 0.3999,-1.5 0.8887,-1.5 0.4888,0 1.1842,-1.575 1.5453,-3.5 0.3612,-1.925 1.0862,-3.5 1.6113,-3.5 0.5251,0 0.9547,-1.5199 0.9547,-3.37756 0,-1.85765 0.675,-3.93775 1.5,-4.62244 0.825,-0.68469 1.5,-1.79565 1.5,-2.46881 0,-0.67315 0.6474,-2.53055 1.4387,-4.12755 0.7913,-1.597 1.9217,-4.18469 2.512,-5.75041 0.5904,-1.56572 1.968,-3.0807 3.0613,-3.36663 1.4042,-0.36718 1.988,-1.36669 1.988,-3.40323 0,-2.52624 0.3654,-2.88337 2.9501,-2.88337 2.89,0 2.9562,-0.11717 3.25,-5.75 0.2839,-5.44331 0.4466,-5.76688 3.0499,-6.06642 2.3031,-0.26501 2.75,-0.79311 2.75,-3.25 0,-2.59287 0.3484,-2.93358 3,-2.93358 3,0 3,0 3,-6 0,-6 0,-6 3,-6 2.8054,0 3,-0.24572 3,-3.78856 0,-4.27117 2.4731,-9.74298 6.0774,-13.44629 1.3324,-1.36908 3.0844,-3.45132 3.8934,-4.62719 1.7187,-2.49847 3.3185,-2.70582 5.3331,-0.69124 1.2622,1.26228 2.0681,0.73752 6.3214,-4.11641 2.6811,-3.05971 5.2862,-6.29824 5.7892,-7.19671 1.2653,-2.26011 2.703,-3.10037 5.3355,-3.11829 1.9898,-0.0135 2.25,-0.52368 2.25,-4.41172 0,-3.81348 0.488,-4.82485 3.6803,-7.62777 3.7622,-3.30326 10.8913,-8.08885 17.8948,-12.01233 5.9469,-3.33154 9.9747,-6.87689 30.2643,-26.63888 16.7672,-16.33124 23.0452,-21.90694 38.9433,-34.58705 11.7869,-9.40104 15.561,-12.45627 19.1315,-15.48756 2.1055,-1.7875 4.3995,-3.25 5.0977,-3.25 0.6982,0 3.1187,-1.62111 5.3788,-3.60247 9.6082,-8.42318 34.5021,-26.60301 42.6844,-31.17206 2.9837,-1.66615 8.2649,-4.63958 11.736,-6.60763 9.235,-5.2361 15.3366,-7.74886 18.1794,-7.48666 3.8101,0.35143 7.1233,-1.04998 11.2624,-4.76386 2.9736,-2.66812 4.6063,-3.36732 7.8627,-3.36732 2.9514,0 4.9943,-0.7315 7.2472,-2.59499 5.59,-4.6238 13.9621,-9.37701 17.5931,-9.98832 1.9493,-0.32818 5.7941,-1.65303 8.5441,-2.94412 2.75,-1.29109 9.7115,-4.19627 15.47,-6.45596 10.8939,-4.27486 20.3674,-10.46818 22.2149,-14.52308 0.591,-1.29709 2.4787,-2.8763 4.1948,-3.50936 1.7162,-0.63305 3.9017,-1.56346 4.8567,-2.06758 0.9551,-0.50413 3.2626,-0.91659 5.1279,-0.91659 1.8653,0 5.007,-0.675 6.9815,-1.5 1.9745,-0.825 4.981,-1.5 6.6811,-1.5 1.7002,0 6.7771,-1.77626 11.2821,-3.94725 4.5051,-2.17099 11.5144,-5.13889 15.5763,-6.59534 4.0619,-1.45644 9.4619,-3.80426 12,-5.21736 2.5381,-1.4131 6.1897,-3.44736 8.1147,-4.52057 1.925,-1.07322 3.725,-2.2619 4,-2.64153 0.275,-0.37962 4.55,-2.36907 9.5,-4.42099 4.95,-2.05192 9.7814,-4.16416 10.7364,-4.69386 0.9551,-0.52971 2.8972,-0.9631 4.3158,-0.9631 1.4186,0 3.4018,-0.44021 4.4072,-0.97825 1.0053,-0.53803 7.0097,-2.07579 13.3431,-3.41724 6.3334,-1.34144 12.5688,-3.11794 13.8564,-3.94777 1.2876,-0.82983 4.1411,-1.81397 6.3411,-2.18696 2.2,-0.373 11.346,-2.43128 20.3245,-4.57396 12.707,-3.03247 17.4714,-3.76496 21.5,-3.30543 4.321,0.49288 6.4413,0.0801 12.8421,-2.50002 4.2166,-1.6997 8.0921,-3.09037 8.6122,-3.09037 1.1489,0 19.9203,-5.76806 22.7212,-6.98179 1.1,-0.47666 6.05,-1.84448 11,-3.0396 4.95,-1.19512 11.25,-2.97875 14,-3.96363 3.3917,-1.2147 8.2165,-1.83433 15,-1.92639 11.509,-0.15618 27.0817,-3.96225 39,-9.53186 8.3155,-3.88599 15.7959,-5.62769 28,-6.51942 4.95,-0.36169 9.675,-0.95318 10.5,-1.31443 2.0001,-0.87582 26.8123,-3.9238 35,-4.29948 8.1688,-0.37482 15.0611,-1.90375 20.046,-4.44688 2.1309,-1.08708 5.5798,-1.97075 7.6642,-1.9637 3.9167,0.0132 11.5501,-1.47751 28.7898,-5.62249 5.5,-1.32238 10.7399,-2.40117 11.6441,-2.39733 0.9043,0.004 8.534,-2.243 16.955,-4.993 9.493,-3.10012 17.085,-5 19.9801,-5 2.5681,0 6.5825,-0.675 8.9208,-1.5 2.3383,-0.825 6.1914,-1.500004 8.5624,-1.500004 4.1261,0 4.3243,0.13835 4.6242,3.227874 0.2884,2.97009 0.6728,3.29216 4.8134,4.03295 4.6839,0.83799 14.6759,0.46039 19.0045,-0.71819 2.1476,-0.58476 2.6695,-0.24455 3.6631,2.38773 0.9218,2.44207 1.7443,3.06964 4.023,3.06964 1.5754,0 3.7933,-0.65062 4.9286,-1.44582 2.4028,-1.68301 24.14,-3.3037 54.3808,-4.05455 10.725,-0.26629 26.7,-0.98944 35.5,-1.60699 14.6125,-1.02545 41.6756,-0.52016 43.8417,0.81857 1.1034,0.68194 12.2132,0.68194 13.3166,0 2.1661,-1.33873 29.2292,-1.84402 43.8417,-0.81857 8.8,0.61755 24.775,1.3407 35.5,1.60699 30.2408,0.75085 51.978,2.37154 54.3808,4.05455 1.1353,0.7952 3.3532,1.44582 4.9286,1.44582 2.2787,0 3.1012,-0.62757 4.023,-3.06964 0.9936,-2.63228 1.5155,-2.97249 3.6631,-2.38773 4.3286,1.17858 14.3206,1.55618 19.0045,0.71819 4.1406,-0.74079 4.525,-1.06286 4.8134,-4.03295 0.2999,-3.089524 0.4981,-3.227874 4.6242,-3.227874 2.371,0 6.2241,0.675004 8.5624,1.500004 2.3383,0.825 6.3527,1.5 8.9208,1.5 2.8951,0 10.4871,1.89988 19.9801,5 8.421,2.75 16.0507,4.99685 16.955,4.993 0.9042,-0.004 6.1441,1.07495 11.6441,2.39733 17.2397,4.14498 24.8731,5.63573 28.7898,5.62249 2.0844,-0.007 5.5333,0.87662 7.6642,1.9637 4.9849,2.54313 11.8772,4.07206 20.046,4.44688 8.1877,0.37568 32.9999,3.42366 35,4.29948 0.825,0.36125 5.55,0.95274 10.5,1.31443 12.2041,0.89173 19.6845,2.63343 28,6.51942 11.9183,5.56961 27.491,9.37568 39,9.53186 6.7835,0.0921 11.6083,0.71169 15,1.92639 2.75,0.98488 9.05,2.76851 14,3.96363 4.95,1.19512 9.9,2.56294 11,3.0396 2.8009,1.21373 21.5723,6.98179 22.7212,6.98179 0.5201,0 4.3956,1.39067 8.6122,3.09037 6.4008,2.58013 8.5211,2.9929 12.8421,2.50002 4.0286,-0.45953 8.793,0.27296 21.5,3.30543 8.9785,2.14268 18.1245,4.20096 20.3245,4.57396 2.2,0.37299 5.0535,1.35713 6.3411,2.18696 1.2876,0.82983 7.523,2.60633 13.8564,3.94777 6.3334,1.34145 12.3378,2.87921 13.3431,3.41724 1.0054,0.53804 2.9886,0.97825 4.4072,0.97825 1.4186,0 3.3607,0.43339 4.3158,0.9631 0.955,0.5297 5.7864,2.64194 10.7364,4.69386 4.95,2.05192 9.225,4.04137 9.5,4.42099 0.275,0.37963 2.075,1.56831 4,2.64153 1.925,1.07321 5.5766,3.10747 8.1147,4.52057 2.5381,1.4131 7.9381,3.76092 12,5.21736 4.0619,1.45645 11.0712,4.42435 15.5763,6.59534 4.505,2.17099 9.5819,3.94725 11.2821,3.94725 1.7001,0 4.7066,0.675 6.6811,1.5 1.9745,0.825 5.1162,1.5 6.9815,1.5 1.8653,0 4.1728,0.41246 5.1279,0.91659 0.955,0.50412 3.1405,1.43453 4.8567,2.06758 1.7161,0.63306 3.6038,2.21227 4.1948,3.50936 1.8475,4.0549 11.321,10.24822 22.2149,14.52308 5.7585,2.25969 12.72,5.16487 15.47,6.45596 2.75,1.29109 6.5948,2.61594 8.5441,2.94412 3.631,0.61131 12.0031,5.36452 17.5931,9.98832 2.2529,1.86349 4.2958,2.59499 7.2472,2.59499 3.2564,0 4.8891,0.6992 7.8627,3.36732 4.1391,3.71388 7.4523,5.11529 11.2624,4.76386 2.8428,-0.2622 8.9444,2.25056 18.1794,7.48666 3.4711,1.96805 8.7523,4.94148 11.736,6.60763 8.1823,4.56905 33.0762,22.74888 42.6844,31.17206 2.2601,1.98136 4.6806,3.60247 5.3788,3.60247 0.6982,0 2.9922,1.4625 5.0977,3.25 3.5705,3.03129 7.3446,6.08652 19.1315,15.48756 15.8981,12.68011 22.1761,18.25581 38.9433,34.58705 20.2896,19.76199 24.3174,23.30734 30.2643,26.63888 7.0035,3.92348 14.1326,8.70907 17.8948,12.01233 3.1923,2.80292 3.6803,3.81429 3.6803,7.62777 0,3.88804 0.2602,4.39818 2.25,4.41172 2.6325,0.0179 4.0702,0.85818 5.3355,3.11829 0.503,0.89847 3.1081,4.137 5.7892,7.19671 4.2533,4.85393 5.0592,5.37869 6.3214,4.11641 2.0146,-2.01458 3.6144,-1.80723 5.3331,0.69124 0.809,1.17587 2.561,3.25811 3.8934,4.62719 3.6043,3.70331 6.0774,9.17512 6.0774,13.44629 0,3.54284 0.1946,3.78856 3,3.78856 3,0 3,0 3,6 0,6 0,6 3,6 2.6516,0 3,0.34071 3,2.93358 0,2.45689 0.4469,2.98499 2.75,3.25 2.6033,0.29954 2.766,0.62311 3.0499,6.06642 0.2938,5.63283 0.36,5.75 3.25,5.75 2.5847,0 2.9501,0.35713 2.9501,2.88337 0,2.03654 0.5838,3.03605 1.988,3.40323 1.0933,0.28593 2.4709,1.80091 3.0613,3.36663 0.5903,1.56572 1.7207,4.15341 2.512,5.75041 0.7913,1.597 1.4387,3.4544 1.4387,4.12755 0,0.67316 0.675,1.78412 1.5,2.46881 0.825,0.68469 1.5,2.76479 1.5,4.62244 0,1.85766 0.4296,3.37756 0.9547,3.37756 0.5251,0 1.2501,1.575 1.6113,3.5 0.3611,1.925 1.0565,3.5 1.5453,3.5 0.4888,0 0.8887,0.675 0.8887,1.5 0,0.825 0.4641,1.5 1.0314,1.5 0.5672,0 1.3213,0.7875 1.6756,1.75 0.3544,0.9625 2.3653,4.49863 4.4687,7.85806 2.1033,3.35944 3.8243,6.44418 3.8243,6.85498 0,0.4108 1.35,2.74723 3,5.19207 1.65,2.44483 3,4.69533 3,5.0011 0,0.30577 1.0904,1.4137 2.4232,2.46206 1.3328,1.04835 2.7185,3.25062 3.0795,4.89392 0.3609,1.64329 1.0347,2.98781 1.4973,2.98781 0.4626,0 1.1365,1.34484 1.4975,2.98853 0.361,1.6437 1.0718,3.24525 1.5794,3.55902 1.5107,0.93363 1.0561,4.18596 -1.0732,7.67828 -2.69,4.41204 -2.5833,4.66149 1.7463,4.08151 l 3.75,-0.50234 5.8672,23.8475 c 3.227,13.11613 8.275,32.8475 11.2177,43.8475 2.9427,11 6.5027,25.4 7.9111,32 1.4084,6.6 5.0176,22.35 8.0204,35 3.9885,16.80217 6.5408,30.93399 9.4716,52.44284 2.2066,16.19356 4.012,30.31794 4.012,31.38752 0,1.06957 -7.0292,19.54529 -15.6203,41.05716 -8.5912,21.51186 -20.2593,52.95859 -25.929,69.88162 l -10.3085,30.76914 -15.6457,17.51298 -15.6456,17.5131 9.4206,13.2178 c 5.1814,7.26983 25.7437,37.70783 45.6941,67.64013 l 36.2735,54.4224 10.2211,24.5776 c 5.6215,13.5177 13.7379,35.1527 18.0362,48.0777 4.2984,12.925 12.2586,35.875 17.6893,51 9.0943,25.3282 11.1436,32.5543 25.9482,91.5 l 16.0742,64 2.0201,77.5 2.0202,77.5 -9.0979,73 c -5.0038,40.15 -11.3765,91.9 -14.1615,115 -2.785,23.1 -7.7469,63.4558 -11.0263,89.6795 l -5.9627,47.6795 0,31.3997 0,31.3997 -13.5,52.0473 c -7.425,28.6261 -13.5014,53.1155 -13.5031,54.4208 0,1.3054 1.6434,9.7985 3.6557,18.8735 l 3.6588,16.5 9.8785,17.7278 9.8784,17.7279 4.0989,20.2721 4.099,20.2722 -2.099,73.5 -2.0989,73.5 -3.8908,15.1282 -3.8908,15.1281 -15.6437,21.4997 c -8.604,11.8248 -16.206,21.9314 -16.8933,22.4591 -1.6895,1.297 -57.372,16.9932 -82.5181,23.2607 -20.1542,5.0233 -54.3392,11.0242 -62.8012,11.0242 -4.256,0 -4.4304,-0.1181 -4.4304,-3 l 0,-3 -56.5069,0 c -47.0759,0 -60.72,-0.3296 -81.75,-1.9746 -16.4076,-1.2835 -53.4194,-2.6938 -105.7431,-4.0293 -44.275,-1.1301 -101.2,-2.9091 -126.5,-3.9534 l -46,-1.8986 -34.5,-6.0581 c -29.0438,-5.1 -41.1918,-6.6929 -76.8132,-10.072 -55.0335,-5.2207 -60.8982,-5.2143 -107.1868,0.1168 l -36.5,4.2037 -38,-4.0001 -38,-4.0001 -37.5,3.7985 c -36.9664,3.7443 -38.1098,3.7989 -80.35,3.8328 l -42.85,0.034 -21.0574,-11.5 c -11.5815,-6.325 -21.774,-11.4891 -22.65,-11.4759 -0.8759,0.013 -10.3676,2.7677 -21.0926,6.1209 -10.725,3.3532 -20.625,6.0967 -22,6.0967 -1.375,0 -11.275,-2.7435 -22,-6.0967 -10.725,-3.3532 -20.2167,-6.1076 -21.0926,-6.1209 -0.876,-0.013 -11.0685,5.1509 -22.65,11.4759 l -21.0574,11.5 -42.85,-0.034 c -42.2402,-0.034 -43.3836,-0.088 -80.35,-3.8328 l -37.5,-3.7985 -38,4.0001 -38,4.0001 -36.5,-4.2037 c -46.2886,-5.3311 -52.1533,-5.3375 -107.1868,-0.1168 -35.6214,3.3791 -47.7694,4.972 -76.8132,10.072 l -34.5,6.0581 -46,1.8986 c -25.3,1.0443 -82.225,2.8233 -126.5,3.9534 -52.3237,1.3355 -89.3355,2.7458 -105.7431,4.0293 -21.03,1.645 -34.6741,1.9746 -81.75,1.9746 l -56.5069,0 0,3 c 0,2.9988 0,3 -5.75,2.8851 -3.1625,-0.063 -13.6693,-1.3919 -23.3484,-2.9528 z m 27.0984,-1.9323 0,-3 54.25,-0.01 c 45.3099,-0.01 58.2051,-0.3354 78.25,-1.9919 15.8644,-1.311 49.7629,-2.6562 100,-3.9683 41.8,-1.0918 100.075,-2.9185 129.5,-4.0595 l 53.5,-2.0746 34.4157,-6.0181 c 28.0876,-4.9116 41.8783,-6.7382 75,-9.9339 55.479,-5.3529 71.0717,-5.3565 115.5843,-0.026 l 32,3.8317 38,-3.9915 38,-3.9915 41.5,4.1308 c 40.6923,4.0504 42.2433,4.1305 79.6943,4.1163 l 38.1943,-0.015 21.9474,-12 c 12.0711,-6.6 22.5587,-11.9947 23.3057,-11.9883 0.7471,0.01 10.3583,2.7771 21.3583,6.1571 11,3.38 21.125,6.1454 22.5,6.1454 1.375,0 11.5,-2.7654 22.5,-6.1454 11,-3.38 20.6112,-6.1507 21.3583,-6.1571 0.747,-0.01 11.2346,5.3883 23.3057,11.9883 l 21.9474,12 38.1943,0.015 c 37.451,0.014 39.002,-0.066 79.6943,-4.1163 l 41.5,-4.1308 38,3.9915 38,3.9915 32,-3.8317 c 44.5126,-5.33 60.1053,-5.3264 115.5843,0.026 33.1217,3.1957 46.9124,5.0223 75,9.9339 l 34.4157,6.0181 53.5,2.0746 c 29.425,1.141 87.7,2.9677 129.5,4.0595 50.2371,1.3121 84.1356,2.6573 100,3.9683 20.0449,1.6565 32.9401,1.9847 78.25,1.9919 l 54.25,0.01 0,3 c 0,1.65 0.4609,3 1.0242,3 0.5632,0 10.1257,-1.3886 21.25,-3.0857 25.5829,-3.9029 67.9538,-14.5076 121.9542,-30.5228 0.9507,-0.2819 8.9403,-10.4032 17.7548,-22.4917 l 16.0263,-21.979 3.9703,-16.2104 3.9703,-16.2104 1.928,-71 1.9279,-71 -3.9913,-19.8938 -3.9914,-19.8938 -9.9524,-17.8458 -9.9523,-17.8459 -4.1236,-18.4859 -4.1235,-18.486 14.183,-54.7744 14.183,-54.7744 -0.019,-32.3267 -0.019,-32.3267 5.4728,-43.6733 c 3.01,-24.0203 9.0975,-73.5983 13.5278,-110.1733 4.4304,-36.575 10.9263,-89.45 14.4354,-117.5 l 6.3802,-51 -1.9956,-75.5 -1.9956,-75.5 -15.8538,-63.5 c -14.3257,-57.3797 -16.7358,-65.9578 -25.0056,-89 -5.0335,-14.025 -13.322,-37.875 -18.4189,-53 -5.0969,-15.125 -13.6444,-38.0247 -18.9943,-50.8882 l -9.7272,-23.3882 -35.0611,-52.6118 c -19.2836,-28.9365 -39.9442,-59.4399 -45.9126,-67.7853 -5.9683,-8.34553 -10.8515,-15.70353 -10.8515,-16.35123 0,-0.6478 7.126,-9.1197 15.8356,-18.8265 l 15.8355,-17.64876 8.7642,-26.5 c 4.8202,-14.575 16.4453,-45.84975 25.8335,-69.49944 l 17.0694,-42.99944 -3.7934,-30.50056 c -4.1556,-33.41227 -3.4104,-29.98336 -30.2654,-139.26949 -9.7743,-39.77653 -11.9927,-47.65845 -13.2589,-47.10858 -0.8363,0.3632 -2.758,0.8728 -4.2705,1.13244 -2.4233,0.41599 -2.75,0.15924 -2.75,-2.1613 0,-1.44836 1.117,-4.40282 2.4822,-6.56547 1.3652,-2.16265 2.0749,-4.18387 1.577,-4.4916 -0.4979,-0.30772 -1.2007,-1.90433 -1.5617,-3.54803 -0.3605,-1.64369 -1.0344,-2.98853 -1.497,-2.98853 -0.4626,0 -1.1364,-1.34452 -1.4973,-2.98781 -0.361,-1.6433 -1.7467,-3.84557 -3.0795,-4.89392 -1.3328,-1.04836 -2.4232,-2.15629 -2.4232,-2.46206 0,-0.30577 -1.35,-2.55627 -3,-5.0011 -1.65,-2.44484 -3,-4.78127 -3,-5.19207 0,-0.4108 -1.8,-3.59701 -4,-7.08047 -2.2,-3.48345 -4,-6.8087 -4,-7.38944 0,-0.58075 -0.675,-1.31492 -1.5,-1.6315 -0.825,-0.31659 -1.5,-1.20246 -1.5,-1.96862 0,-0.76615 -0.3999,-1.39301 -0.8887,-1.39301 -0.4888,0 -1.1842,-1.575 -1.5453,-3.5 -0.3612,-1.925 -1.0862,-3.5 -1.6113,-3.5 -0.5251,0 -0.9547,-1.5199 -0.9547,-3.37756 0,-1.85765 -0.675,-3.93775 -1.5,-4.62244 -0.825,-0.68469 -1.5,-1.79565 -1.5,-2.46881 0,-0.67315 -0.6474,-2.53055 -1.4387,-4.12755 -0.7913,-1.597 -1.9217,-4.18469 -2.512,-5.75041 -0.5904,-1.56572 -1.968,-3.0807 -3.0613,-3.36663 -1.4042,-0.36718 -1.988,-1.36669 -1.988,-3.40323 0,-2.52624 -0.3654,-2.88337 -2.9501,-2.88337 -2.89,0 -2.9562,-0.11717 -3.25,-5.75 -0.2839,-5.44331 -0.4466,-5.76688 -3.0499,-6.06642 -2.3031,-0.26501 -2.75,-0.79311 -2.75,-3.25 0,-2.59287 -0.3484,-2.93358 -3,-2.93358 -3,0 -3,0 -3,-6 0,-6 0,-6 -3,-6 -2.8054,0 -3,-0.24572 -3,-3.78856 0,-4.23802 -2.4325,-9.65596 -6.0774,-13.5361 -1.3324,-1.41847 -3.0727,-3.35047 -3.8672,-4.29333 -0.9506,-1.12803 -1.5776,-1.31549 -1.8334,-0.54815 -0.2137,0.64138 -1.347,1.16614 -2.5183,1.16614 -2.32,0 -12.1562,-9.69969 -13.2131,-13.0297 -0.4826,-1.52038 -1.5234,-1.9703 -4.558,-1.9703 l -3.9326,0 0,-4.90106 c 0,-4.73258 -0.1977,-5.06924 -5.75,-9.79363 -5.889,-5.01082 -8.2742,-6.6723 -14.9362,-10.40421 -5.8273,-3.26429 -9.9433,-6.89211 -30.1532,-26.57649 -16.7672,-16.33124 -23.0452,-21.90694 -38.9433,-34.58705 -11.7869,-9.40104 -15.561,-12.45627 -19.1315,-15.48756 -2.1055,-1.7875 -4.3995,-3.25 -5.0977,-3.25 -0.6982,0 -3.1187,-1.62111 -5.3788,-3.60247 -9.6082,-8.42318 -34.5021,-26.60301 -42.6844,-31.17206 -2.9837,-1.66615 -8.2649,-4.63958 -11.736,-6.60763 -9.3879,-5.3228 -14.8374,-7.52251 -17.1427,-6.91967 -2.8404,0.74277 -7.8382,-1.43122 -12.2396,-5.32411 -3.0663,-2.71197 -4.2617,-3.17447 -7.0397,-2.72366 -2.7527,0.4467 -4.0837,-0.0505 -7.5048,-2.80369 -6.882,-5.5385 -13.3225,-9.15793 -18.6858,-10.50107 -2.792,-0.6992 -6.8763,-2.17093 -9.0763,-3.27051 -2.2,-1.09958 -8.7115,-3.83699 -14.47,-6.08314 -10.884,-4.24539 -20.3616,-10.43089 -22.2149,-14.49846 -0.591,-1.29709 -2.4787,-2.8763 -4.1948,-3.50936 -1.7162,-0.63305 -3.9017,-1.56346 -4.8567,-2.06758 -0.9551,-0.50413 -3.3472,-0.91659 -5.3158,-0.91659 -1.9686,0 -4.4932,-0.4891 -5.6102,-1.08689 -1.1169,-0.59779 -3.9177,-1.21409 -6.2238,-1.36957 -2.3566,-0.15888 -7.8982,-2.06851 -12.6534,-4.36036 -4.6532,-2.24272 -11.7838,-5.26932 -15.8457,-6.72577 -4.0619,-1.45644 -9.4619,-3.80426 -12,-5.21736 -2.5381,-1.4131 -6.1897,-3.44736 -8.1147,-4.52057 -1.925,-1.07322 -3.725,-2.2619 -4,-2.64153 -0.275,-0.37962 -4.55,-2.36907 -9.5,-4.42099 -4.95,-2.05192 -9.7814,-4.16416 -10.7364,-4.69386 -0.9551,-0.52971 -2.8972,-0.9631 -4.3158,-0.9631 -1.4186,0 -3.4018,-0.44021 -4.4072,-0.97825 -1.0053,-0.53803 -7.0097,-2.07579 -13.3431,-3.41724 -6.3334,-1.34144 -12.5688,-3.10521 -13.8564,-3.91948 -1.2876,-0.81426 -5.998,-2.20394 -10.4676,-3.08816 -4.4695,-0.88423 -13.4247,-2.91839 -19.9004,-4.52035 -8.3946,-2.0767 -12.4477,-2.65649 -14.1215,-2.0201 -2.7529,1.04666 -10.9925,-0.30224 -15.2294,-2.49321 -1.5834,-0.81884 -5.9712,-2.36539 -9.7506,-3.43679 -10.565,-2.99501 -20.6582,-6.12729 -22.8716,-7.09787 -1.1,-0.48235 -6.05,-1.84859 -11,-3.03609 -4.95,-1.1875 -10.7345,-2.81176 -12.8544,-3.60946 -2.1255,-0.7998 -8.7827,-1.64517 -14.8414,-1.88466 -12.5666,-0.49673 -28.5074,-4.42876 -40.3042,-9.94161 -8.1635,-3.81494 -15.5091,-5.55813 -28,-6.64472 -4.95,-0.4306 -12.15,-1.26924 -16,-1.86365 -3.85,-0.59441 -10.6,-1.48814 -15,-1.98607 -4.4,-0.49793 -9.27,-1.22431 -10.8221,-1.61418 -1.6512,-0.41472 -3.7397,-0.21779 -5.0335,0.47459 -1.7698,0.94717 -2.8035,0.87461 -5.1778,-0.36347 -1.6316,-0.8508 -3.8666,-1.55408 -4.9666,-1.56284 -1.1,-0.009 -4.4072,-1.13653 -7.3493,-2.50616 -2.9421,-1.36963 -6.9921,-2.48446 -9,-2.47741 -3.7856,0.0133 -11.5382,-1.50809 -28.6507,-5.62249 -5.5,-1.32238 -10.7399,-2.40117 -11.6441,-2.39733 -0.9043,0.004 -8.534,-2.243 -16.955,-4.993 -9.493,-3.10012 -17.085,-5 -19.9801,-5 -2.5681,0 -6.5825,-0.675 -8.9208,-1.5 -6.8642,-2.42183 -8.8195,-2.05407 -9.1866,1.72787 -0.2882,2.96864 -0.6748,3.29317 -4.8134,4.04103 -2.475,0.44724 -8.4168,0.6822 -13.2041,0.52213 -8.1944,-0.27399 -8.7641,-0.15928 -9.7285,1.95897 -0.8553,1.87844 -1.817,2.25 -5.8235,2.25 -2.6394,0 -5.7278,-0.65062 -6.8631,-1.44582 -2.2353,-1.56566 -25.1013,-3.3475 -46.8808,-3.65319 -6.6,-0.0926 -22.35,-0.81554 -35,-1.60645 -21.984,-1.37449 -47.5,-1.02045 -47.5,0.65907 0,0.39218 -4.05,0.71306 -9,0.71306 -4.95,0 -9,-0.32088 -9,-0.71306 0,-1.67952 -25.516,-2.03356 -47.5,-0.65907 -12.65,0.79091 -28.4,1.51381 -35,1.60645 -21.7795,0.30569 -44.6455,2.08753 -46.8808,3.65319 -1.1353,0.7952 -4.2237,1.44582 -6.8631,1.44582 -4.0065,0 -4.9682,-0.37156 -5.8235,-2.25 -0.9644,-2.11825 -1.5341,-2.23296 -9.7285,-1.95897 -4.7873,0.16007 -10.7291,-0.0749 -13.2041,-0.52213 -4.1386,-0.74786 -4.5252,-1.07239 -4.8134,-4.04103 -0.3671,-3.78194 -2.3224,-4.1497 -9.1866,-1.72787 -2.3383,0.825 -6.3527,1.5 -8.9208,1.5 -2.8951,0 -10.4871,1.89988 -19.9801,5 -8.421,2.75 -16.0507,4.99685 -16.955,4.993 -0.9042,-0.004 -6.1441,1.07495 -11.6441,2.39733 -17.1125,4.1144 -24.8651,5.63578 -28.6507,5.62249 -2.0079,-0.007 -6.0579,1.10778 -9,2.47741 -2.9421,1.36963 -6.2493,2.4974 -7.3493,2.50616 -1.1,0.009 -3.335,0.71204 -4.9666,1.56284 -2.3743,1.23808 -3.408,1.31064 -5.1778,0.36347 -1.2938,-0.69238 -3.3823,-0.88931 -5.0335,-0.47459 -1.5521,0.38987 -6.4221,1.11625 -10.8221,1.61418 -4.4,0.49793 -11.15,1.39166 -15,1.98607 -3.85,0.59441 -11.05,1.43305 -16,1.86365 -12.4909,1.08659 -19.8365,2.82978 -28,6.64472 -11.7968,5.51285 -27.7376,9.44488 -40.3042,9.94161 -6.0587,0.23949 -12.7159,1.08486 -14.8414,1.88466 -2.1199,0.7977 -7.9044,2.42196 -12.8544,3.60946 -4.95,1.1875 -9.9,2.55374 -11,3.03609 -2.2134,0.97058 -12.3066,4.10286 -22.8716,7.09787 -3.7794,1.0714 -8.1672,2.61795 -9.7506,3.43679 -4.2369,2.19097 -12.4765,3.53987 -15.2294,2.49321 -1.6738,-0.63639 -5.7269,-0.0566 -14.1215,2.0201 -6.4757,1.60196 -15.4309,3.63612 -19.9004,4.52035 -4.4696,0.88422 -9.18,2.2739 -10.4676,3.08816 -1.2876,0.81427 -7.523,2.57804 -13.8564,3.91948 -6.3334,1.34145 -12.3378,2.87921 -13.3431,3.41724 -1.0054,0.53804 -2.9886,0.97825 -4.4072,0.97825 -1.4186,0 -3.3607,0.43339 -4.3158,0.9631 -0.955,0.5297 -5.7864,2.64194 -10.7364,4.69386 -4.95,2.05192 -9.225,4.04137 -9.5,4.42099 -0.275,0.37963 -2.075,1.56831 -4,2.64153 -1.925,1.07321 -5.5766,3.10747 -8.1147,4.52057 -2.5381,1.4131 -7.9381,3.76092 -12,5.21736 -4.0619,1.45645 -11.1925,4.48305 -15.8457,6.72577 -4.7552,2.29185 -10.2968,4.20148 -12.6534,4.36036 -2.3061,0.15548 -5.1069,0.77178 -6.2238,1.36957 -1.117,0.59779 -3.6416,1.08689 -5.6102,1.08689 -1.9686,0 -4.3607,0.41246 -5.3158,0.91659 -0.955,0.50412 -3.1405,1.43453 -4.8567,2.06758 -1.7161,0.63306 -3.6038,2.21227 -4.1948,3.50936 -1.8533,4.06757 -11.3309,10.25307 -22.2149,14.49846 -5.7585,2.24615 -12.27,4.98356 -14.47,6.08314 -2.2,1.09958 -6.2843,2.57131 -9.0763,3.27051 -5.3633,1.34314 -11.8038,4.96257 -18.6858,10.50107 -3.4211,2.75314 -4.7521,3.25039 -7.5048,2.80369 -2.778,-0.45081 -3.9734,0.0117 -7.0397,2.72366 -4.4014,3.89289 -9.3992,6.06688 -12.2396,5.32411 -2.3053,-0.60284 -7.7548,1.59687 -17.1427,6.91967 -3.4711,1.96805 -8.7523,4.94148 -11.736,6.60763 -8.1823,4.56905 -33.0762,22.74888 -42.6844,31.17206 -2.2601,1.98136 -4.6806,3.60247 -5.3788,3.60247 -0.6982,0 -2.9922,1.4625 -5.0977,3.25 -3.5705,3.03129 -7.3446,6.08652 -19.1315,15.48756 -15.8981,12.68011 -22.1761,18.25581 -38.9433,34.58705 -20.2099,19.68438 -24.3259,23.3122 -30.1532,26.57649 -6.662,3.73191 -9.0472,5.39339 -14.9362,10.40421 -5.5523,4.72439 -5.75,5.06105 -5.75,9.79363 l 0,4.90106 -3.9326,0 c -3.0346,0 -4.0754,0.44992 -4.558,1.9703 -1.0569,3.33001 -10.8931,13.0297 -13.2131,13.0297 -1.1713,0 -2.3046,-0.52476 -2.5183,-1.16614 -0.2558,-0.76734 -0.8828,-0.57988 -1.8334,0.54815 -0.7945,0.94286 -2.5348,2.87486 -3.8672,4.29333 -3.6449,3.88014 -6.0774,9.29808 -6.0774,13.5361 0,3.54284 -0.1946,3.78856 -3,3.78856 -3,0 -3,0 -3,6 0,6 0,6 -3,6 -2.6516,0 -3,0.34071 -3,2.93358 0,2.45689 -0.4469,2.98499 -2.75,3.25 -2.6033,0.29954 -2.766,0.62311 -3.0499,6.06642 -0.2938,5.63283 -0.36,5.75 -3.25,5.75 -2.5847,0 -2.9501,0.35713 -2.9501,2.88337 0,2.03654 -0.5838,3.03605 -1.988,3.40323 -1.0933,0.28593 -2.4709,1.80091 -3.0613,3.36663 -0.5903,1.56572 -1.7207,4.15341 -2.512,5.75041 -0.7913,1.597 -1.4387,3.4544 -1.4387,4.12755 0,0.67316 -0.675,1.78412 -1.5,2.46881 -0.825,0.68469 -1.5,2.76479 -1.5,4.62244 0,1.85766 -0.4296,3.37756 -0.9547,3.37756 -0.5251,0 -1.2501,1.575 -1.6113,3.5 -0.3611,1.925 -1.0565,3.5 -1.5453,3.5 -0.4888,0 -0.8887,0.675 -0.8887,1.5 0,0.825 -0.4641,1.5 -1.0314,1.5 -0.5672,0 -1.3213,0.7875 -1.6756,1.75 -0.35439,0.9625 -2.36527,4.49863 -4.46866,7.85806 -2.10339,3.35944 -3.82434,6.44418 -3.82434,6.85498 0,0.4108 -1.35,2.74723 -3,5.19207 -1.65,2.44483 -3,4.69533 -3,5.0011 0,0.30577 -1.09045,1.4137 -2.42322,2.46206 -1.33277,1.04835 -2.71853,3.25062 -3.07946,4.89392 -0.36093,1.64329 -1.03472,2.98781 -1.49732,2.98781 -0.4626,0 -1.13647,1.34484 -1.49748,2.98853 -0.36102,1.6437 -1.06377,3.24031 -1.56168,3.54803 -0.49791,0.30773 0.21171,2.32895 1.57694,4.4916 1.36522,2.16265 2.48222,5.11711 2.48222,6.56547 0,2.32054 -0.32668,2.57729 -2.75,2.1613 -1.5125,-0.25964 -3.43424,-0.76924 -4.27053,-1.13244 -1.26613,-0.54987 -3.48452,7.33205 -13.25885,47.10858 -26.855,109.28613 -26.10985,105.85722 -30.26539,139.26949 l -3.7934,30.50056 17.06938,42.99944 c 9.38816,23.64969 21.01325,54.92444 25.83353,69.49944 l 8.76415,26.5 15.83555,17.64876 c 8.70956,9.7068 15.83556,18.1787 15.83556,18.8265 0,0.6477 -4.8832,8.0057 -10.85153,16.35123 -5.96834,8.3454 -26.62901,38.8488 -45.9126,67.7853 l -35.06107,52.6118 -9.72719,23.3882 c -5.34996,12.8635 -13.8974,35.7632 -18.99431,50.8882 -5.09692,15.125 -13.38544,38.975 -18.41894,53 -8.26975,23.0422 -10.67986,31.6203 -25.0056,89 l -15.85377,63.5 -1.99561,75.5 -1.99561,75.5 6.38024,51 c 3.50913,28.05 10.00504,80.925 14.43535,117.5 4.43032,36.575 10.51786,86.153 13.52788,110.1733 l 5.47276,43.6733 -0.0187,32.3267 -0.0187,32.3267 14.18296,54.7744 14.18296,54.7744 -4.12351,18.486 -4.1235,18.4859 -9.95238,17.8459 -9.95237,17.8458 -3.99137,19.8938 -3.99136,19.8938 1.92795,71 1.92795,71 3.97029,16.2104 3.9703,16.2104 16.02633,21.979 c 8.81448,12.0885 16.80413,22.2098 17.75477,22.4917 53.13124,15.7575 93.8592,26.0463 119.22848,30.12 26.2995,4.2231 24.9999,4.1977 24.9999,0.4885 z" 
            Fill="Red"   
            Stretch="Uniform"
            Stroke="Blue"/>
```

Btw...I understand there are alot of points in the data, but like I said I traced an real image using inkscape, if any one knows an easy way to get rid of some of the points (maybe using Blend) that would also be appreciated (I'm not opposed to making the path more rounded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem was that InkScape actually made a path that represented the border...In otherwords, there were two "lines" that together made an outline of the shape I was trying to get. The fill was actually showing up, but these two lines that represented the border were so close together (and combined with the stroke) I couldn't see the fill I manullay deleted the inner "line" points and as I was doing it the fill started to fill the objected as expected. At first glance it appeared to be a single line, but when I zoomed in dramatically I saw that there were two lines.

There are still alot of points, but here is the final result:

```
<Path x:Name="path" 
            Data="M1019.9016,2413.6161 C1010.2225,2412.0553 993.12249,2408.4899 981.9016,2405.693 956.6459,2399.3979 900.94379,2383.699 899.25033,2382.3989 898.56301,2381.8712 890.96101,2371.7646 882.357,2359.9398 L866.71334,2338.4401 862.82252,2323.312 858.9317,2308.1838 856.83276,2234.6838 854.73383,2161.1838 858.83276,2140.9116 862.9317,2120.6395 872.81013,2102.9116 882.68856,2085.1838 886.34738,2068.6838 C888.35973,2059.6088 890.0048,2051.1157 890.0031,2049.8103 890.0011,2048.505 883.925,2024.0156 876.5,1995.3895 L863,1943.3422 863,1911.9425 863,1880.5428 857.03735,1832.8633 C853.75789,1806.6396 848.79604,1766.2838 846.01102,1743.1838 843.226,1720.0838 836.8533,1668.3338 831.84946,1628.1838 L822.75158,1555.1838 824.77176,1477.6838 826.79195,1400.1838 842.86606,1336.1838 C857.67075,1277.2381 859.71995,1270.012 868.81427,1244.6838 874.24502,1229.5588 882.20521,1206.6088 886.50357,1193.6838 890.80193,1180.7588 898.91826,1159.1238 904.53985,1145.6061 L914.76092,1121.0285 951.03438,1066.6061 C970.98478,1036.6738 991.54712,1006.2358 996.72846,998.96597 L1006.1491,985.74817 990.50345,968.23507 974.85783,950.72209 964.54926,919.95295 C958.87955,903.02992 947.21154,871.58319 938.62035,850.07133 930.02916,828.55946 923,810.08374 923,809.01417 923,807.94459 924.80538,793.82021 927.01195,777.62665 929.9428,756.1178 932.49513,741.98598 936.48359,725.18381 939.48642,712.53381 943.09559,696.78381 944.50398,690.18381 945.91236,683.58381 949.47236,669.18381 952.41509,658.18381 955.35781,647.18381 960.40576,627.45244 963.63275,614.33631 L969.5,590.48881 973.25,590.99115 C977.57955,591.57113 977.68628,591.32168 974.99626,586.90964 972.86699,583.41732 972.41241,580.16499 973.92306,579.23136 974.43075,578.91759 975.1415,577.31604 975.50252,575.67234 975.86353,574.02865 976.5374,572.68381 977,572.68381 977.4626,572.68381 978.13639,571.33929 978.49732,569.696 978.85825,568.0527 980.24401,565.85043 981.57678,564.80208 982.90955,563.75372 984,562.64579 984,562.34002 984,562.03425 985.35,559.78375&#xd;&#xa;987,557.33892 988.65,554.89408 990,552.55765 990,552.14685 990,551.73605 991.72095,548.65131 993.82434,545.29187 995.92773,541.93244 997.93861,538.39631 998.29296,537.43381 998.64731,536.47131 999.40135,535.68381 999.96862,535.68381 1000.5359,535.68381 1001,535.00881 1001,534.18381 1001,533.35881 1001.3999,532.68381 1001.8887,532.68381 1002.3775,532.68381 1003.0729,531.10881 1003.434,529.18381 1003.7952,527.25881&#xd;&#xa;1004.5202,525.68381 1005.0453,525.68381 1005.5704,525.68381 1006,524.16391 1006,522.30625 1006,520.4486 1006.675,518.3685 1007.5,517.68381 1008.325,516.99912 1009,515.88816 1009,515.215 1009,514.54185 1009.6474,512.68445 1010.4387,511.08745 1011.23,509.49045 1012.3604,506.90276 1012.9507,505.33704 1013.5411,503.77132 1014.9187,502.25634 1016.012,501.97041 1017.4162,501.60323 1018,500.60372 1018,498.56718&#xd;&#xa;1018,496.04094 1018.3654,495.68381 1020.9501,495.68381 1023.8401,495.68381 1023.9063,495.56664 1024.2001,489.93381 1024.484,484.4905 1030,483.07428 1030,480.61739 1030,478.02452 1030.3484,477.68381 1033,477.68381 1036,477.68381 1036,465.68381 1039,465.68381 1041.8054,465.68381 1042,465.43809 1042,461.89525 1042,457.62408 1044.4731,452.15227 1048.0774,448.44896 1049.4098,447.07988 1051.1618,444.99764&#xd;&#xa;1051.9708,443.82177 1053.6895,441.3233 1055.2893,441.11595 1057.3039,443.13053 1058.5661,444.39281 1059.372,443.86805 1063.6253,439.01412 1066.3064,435.95441 1068.9115,432.71588 1069.4145,431.81741 1070.6798,429.5573 1072.1175,428.71704 1074.75,428.69912 1076.7398,428.68562 1077,428.17544 1077,424.2874 1077,420.47392 1077.488,419.46255 1080.6803,416.65963 1084.4425,413.35637 1091.5716,408.57078 1098.5751,404.6473 1104.522,401.31576&#xd;&#xa;1108.5498,397.77041 1128.8394,378.00842 1145.6066,361.67718 1151.8846,356.10148 1167.7827,343.42137 1179.5696,334.02033 1183.3437,330.9651 1186.9142,327.93381 1189.0197,326.14631 1191.3137,324.68381 1192.0119,324.68381 1192.7101,324.68381 1195.1306,323.0627 1197.3907,321.08134 1206.9989,312.65816 1231.8928,294.47833 1240.0751,289.90928 1243.0588,288.24313 1248.34,285.2697 1251.8111,283.30165 1261.0461,278.06555 1267.1477,275.55279 1269.9905,275.81499&#xd;&#xa;1273.8006,276.16642 1277.1138,274.76501 1281.2529,271.05113 1284.2265,268.38301 1285.8592,267.68381 1289.1156,267.68381 1292.067,267.68381 1294.1099,266.95231 1296.3628,265.08882 1301.9528,260.46502 1310.3249,255.71181 1313.9559,255.1005 1315.9052,254.77232 1332.2115,247.96011 1337.97,245.70042 1348.8639,241.42556 1358.3374,235.23224 1360.1849,231.17734 1360.7759,229.88025 1362.6636,228.30104 1364.3797,227.66798 1366.0959,227.03493 1368.2814,226.10452&#xd;&#xa;1369.2364,225.6004 1370.1915,225.09627 1372.499,224.68381 1374.3643,224.68381 1376.2296,224.68381 1379.3713,224.00881 1381.3458,223.18381 1383.3203,222.35881 1386.3268,221.68381 1388.0269,221.68381 1389.7271,221.68381 1394.804,219.90755 1399.309,217.73656 1403.8141,215.56557 1410.8234,212.59767 1414.8853,211.14122 1418.9472,209.68478 1424.3472,207.33696 1426.8853,205.92386 1429.4234,204.51076 1433.075,202.4765 1435,201.40329 1436.925,200.33007&#xd;&#xa;1438.725,199.14139 1439,198.76176 1439.275,198.38214 1443.55,196.39269 1448.5,194.34077 1453.45,192.28885 1458.2814,190.17661 1459.2364,189.64691 1460.1915,189.1172 1462.1336,188.68381 1463.5522,188.68381 1464.9708,188.68381 1466.954,188.2436 1467.9594,187.70556 1468.9647,187.16753 1474.9691,185.62977 1481.3025,184.28832 1487.6359,182.94688 1493.8713,181.17038 1495.1589,180.34055 1496.4465,179.51072 1499.3,178.52658 1501.5,178.15359&#xd;&#xa;1503.7,177.78059 1512.846,175.72231 1521.8245,173.57963 1534.5315,170.54716 1539.2959,169.81467 1543.3245,170.2742 1547.6455,170.76708 1549.7658,170.3543 1556.1666,167.77418 1560.3832,166.07448 1564.2587,164.68381 1564.7788,164.68381 1565.9277,164.68381 1584.6991,158.91575 1587.5,157.70202 1588.6,157.22536 1593.55,155.85754 1598.5,154.66242 1603.45,153.4673 1609.75,151.68367 1612.5,150.69879 1615.8917,149.48409 1620.7165,148.86446&#xd;&#xa;1627.5,148.7724 1639.009,148.61622 1654.5817,144.81015 1666.5,139.24054 1674.8155,135.35455 1682.2959,133.61285 1694.5,132.72112 1699.45,132.35943 1704.175,131.76794 1705,131.40669 1707.0001,130.53087 1731.8123,127.48289 1740,127.10721 1748.1688,126.73239 1755.0611,125.20346 1760.046,122.66033 1762.1769,121.57325 1765.6258,120.68958 1767.7102,120.69663 1771.6269,120.70983 1779.2603,119.21912 1796.5,115.07414 1802,113.75176&#xd;&#xa;1807.2399,112.67297 1808.1441,112.67681 1809.0484,112.68081 1816.6781,110.43381 1825.0991,107.68381 1834.5921,104.58369 1842.1841,102.68381 1845.0792,102.68381 1847.6473,102.68381 1851.6617,102.00881 1854,101.18381 1856.3383,100.35881 1860.1914,99.683806 1862.5624,99.683806 1866.6885,99.683806 1866.8867,99.822156 1867.1866,102.91168 1867.475,105.88177 1867.8594,106.20384 1872,106.94463 1876.6839,107.78262 1886.6759,107.40502 1891.0045,106.22644&#xd;&#xa;1893.1521,105.64168 1893.674,105.98189 1894.6676,108.61417 1895.5894,111.05624 1896.4119,111.68381 1898.6906,111.68381 1900.266,111.68381 1902.4839,111.03319 1903.6192,110.23799 1906.022,108.55498 1927.7592,106.93429 1958,106.18344 1968.725,105.91715 1984.7,105.194 1993.5,104.57645 2008.1125,103.551 2035.1756,104.05629 2037.3417,105.39502 2038.4451,106.07696 2049.5549,106.07696 2050.6583,105.39502 2052.8244,104.05629 2079.8875,103.551&#xd;&#xa;2094.5,104.57645 2103.3,105.194 2119.275,105.91715 2130,106.18344 2160.2408,106.93429 2181.978,108.55498 2184.3808,110.23799 2185.5161,111.03319 2187.734,111.68381 2189.3094,111.68381 2191.5881,111.68381 2192.4106,111.05624 2193.3324,108.61417 2194.326,105.98189 2194.8479,105.64168 2196.9955,106.22644 2201.3241,107.40502 2211.3161,107.78262 2216,106.94463 2220.1406,106.20384 2220.525,105.88177 2220.8134,102.91168 2221.1133,99.822156&#xd;&#xa;2221.3115,99.683806 2225.4376,99.683806 2227.8086,99.683806 2231.6617,100.35881 2234,101.18381 2236.3383,102.00881 2240.3527,102.68381 2242.9208,102.68381 2245.8159,102.68381 2253.4079,104.58369 2262.9009,107.68381 2271.3219,110.43381 2278.9516,112.68066 2279.8559,112.67681 2280.7601,112.67281 2286,113.75176 2291.5,115.07414 2308.7397,119.21912 2316.3731,120.70987 2320.2898,120.69663 2322.3742,120.68963 2325.8231,121.57325 2327.954,122.66033&#xd;&#xa;2332.9389,125.20346 2339.8312,126.73239 2348,127.10721 2356.1877,127.48289 2380.9999,130.53087 2383,131.40669 2383.825,131.76794 2388.55,132.35943 2393.5,132.72112 2405.7041,133.61285 2413.1845,135.35455 2421.5,139.24054 2433.4183,144.81015 2448.991,148.61622 2460.5,148.7724 2467.2835,148.8645 2472.1083,149.48409 2475.5,150.69879 2478.25,151.68367 2484.55,153.4673 2489.5,154.66242 2494.45,155.85754 2499.4,157.22536&#xd;&#xa;2500.5,157.70202 2503.3009,158.91575 2522.0723,164.68381 2523.2212,164.68381 2523.7413,164.68381 2527.6168,166.07448 2531.8334,167.77418 2538.2342,170.35431 2540.3545,170.76708 2544.6755,170.2742 2548.7041,169.81467 2553.4685,170.54716 2566.1755,173.57963 2575.154,175.72231 2584.3,177.78059 2586.5,178.15359 2588.7,178.52658 2591.5535,179.51072 2592.8411,180.34055 2594.1287,181.17038 2600.3641,182.94688 2606.6975,184.28832 2613.0309,185.62977&#xd;&#xa;2619.0353,187.16753 2620.0406,187.70556 2621.046,188.2436 2623.0292,188.68381 2624.4478,188.68381 2625.8664,188.68381 2627.8085,189.1172 2628.7636,189.64691 2629.7186,190.17661 2634.55,192.28885 2639.5,194.34077 2644.45,196.39269 2648.725,198.38214 2649,198.76176 2649.275,199.14139 2651.075,200.33007 2653,201.40329 2654.925,202.4765 2658.5766,204.51076 2661.1147,205.92386 2663.6528,207.33696 2669.0528,209.68478 2673.1147,211.14122&#xd;&#xa;2677.1766,212.59767 2684.1859,215.56557 2688.691,217.73656 2693.196,219.90755 2698.2729,221.68381 2699.9731,221.68381 2701.6732,221.68381 2704.6797,222.35881 2706.6542,223.18381 2708.6287,224.00881 2717.8085,225.09627 2718.7636,225.6004 2719.7186,226.10452 2721.9041,227.03493 2723.6203,227.66798 2725.3364,228.30104 2727.2241,229.88025 2727.8151,231.17734 2729.6626,235.23224 2739.1361,241.42556 2750.03,245.70042 2755.7885,247.96011 2762.75,250.86529&#xd;&#xa;2765.5,252.15638 2768.25,253.44747 2772.0948,254.77232 2774.0441,255.1005 2777.6751,255.71181 2786.0472,260.46502 2791.6372,265.08882 2793.8901,266.95231 2795.933,267.68381 2798.8844,267.68381 2802.1408,267.68381 2803.7735,268.38301 2806.7471,271.05113 2810.8862,274.76501 2814.1994,276.16642 2818.0095,275.81499 2820.8523,275.55279 2826.9539,278.06555 2836.1889,283.30165 2839.66,285.2697 2844.9412,288.24313 2847.9249,289.90928 2856.1072,294.47833&#xd;&#xa;2881.0011,312.65816 2890.6093,321.08134 2892.8694,323.0627 2895.2899,324.68381 2895.9881,324.68381 2896.6863,324.68381 2898.9803,326.14631 2901.0858,327.93381 2904.6563,330.9651 2908.4304,334.02033 2920.2173,343.42137 2936.1154,356.10148 2942.3934,361.67718 2959.1606,378.00842 2979.4502,397.77041 2983.478,401.31576 2989.4249,404.6473 2996.4284,408.57078 3003.5575,413.35637 3007.3197,416.65963 3010.512,419.46255 3011,420.47392 3011,424.2874&#xd;&#xa;3011,428.17544 3011.2602,428.68558 3013.25,428.69912 3015.8825,428.71702 3017.3202,429.5573 3018.5855,431.81741 3019.0885,432.71588 3021.6936,435.95441 3024.3747,439.01412 3028.628,443.86805 3029.4339,444.39281 3030.6961,443.13053 3032.7107,441.11595 3034.3105,441.3233 3036.0292,443.82177 3036.8382,444.99764 3038.5902,447.07988 3039.9226,448.44896 3043.5269,452.15227 3046,457.62408 3046,461.89525 3046,465.43809 3046.1946,465.68381&#xd;&#xa;3049,465.68381 3052,465.68381 3052,465.68381 3052,471.68381 3052,477.68381 3058,478.02452 3058,480.61739 3058,483.07428 3058.4469,483.60238 3060.75,483.86739 3063.3533,484.16693 3063.516,484.4905 3063.7999,489.93381 3064.0937,495.56664 3064.1599,495.68381 3067.0499,495.68381 3069.6346,495.68381 3070,496.04094 3070,498.56718 3070,500.60372 3070.5838,501.60323 3071.988,501.97041 3073.0813,502.25634&#xd;&#xa;3074.4589,503.77132 3075.0493,505.33704 3075.6396,506.90276 3076.77,509.49045 3077.5613,511.08745 3078.3526,512.68445 3079,514.54185 3079,515.215 3079,515.88816 3079.675,516.99912 3080.5,517.68381 3081.325,518.3685 3082,520.4486 3082,522.30625 3082,524.16391 3082.4296,525.68381 3082.9547,525.68381 3083.4798,525.68381 3084.2048,527.25881 3084.566,529.18381 3084.9271,531.10881 3085.6225,532.68381 3086.1113,532.68381&#xd;&#xa;3086.6001,532.68381 3087,533.35881 3087,534.18381 3087,535.00881 3087.4641,535.68381 3088.0314,535.68381 3088.5986,535.68381 3089.3527,536.47131 3089.707,537.43381 3090.0614,538.39631 3092.0723,541.93244 3094.1757,545.29187 3096.279,548.65131 3098,551.73605 3098,552.14685 3098,552.55765 3099.35,554.89408 3101,557.33892 3102.65,559.78375 3104,562.03425 3104,562.34002 3104,562.64579 3105.0904,563.75372&#xd;&#xa;3106.4232,564.80208 3107.756,565.85043 3109.1417,568.0527 3109.5027,569.696 3109.8636,571.33929 3110.5374,572.68381 3111,572.68381 3111.4626,572.68381 3112.1365,574.02865 3112.4975,575.67234 3112.8585,577.31604 3113.5693,578.91759 3114.0769,579.23136 3115.5876,580.16499 3115.133,583.41732 3113.0037,586.90964 3110.3137,591.32168 3110.4204,591.57113 3114.75,590.99115 L3118.5,590.48881 3124.3672,614.33631 C3127.5942,627.45244 3132.6422,647.18381 3135.5849,658.18381 3138.5276,669.18381 3142.0876,683.58381 3143.496,690.18381 3144.9044,696.78381 3148.5136,712.53381 3151.5164,725.18381 3155.5049,741.98598 3158.0572,756.1178 3160.988,777.62665 3163.1946,793.82021 3165,807.94459 3165,809.01417 3165,810.08374 3157.9708,828.55946 3149.3797,850.07133 3140.7885,871.58319 3129.1204,903.02992 3123.4507,919.95295 L3113.1422,950.72209 3097.4965,968.23507 3081.8509,985.74817 3091.2715,998.96597 C3096.4529,1006.2358 3117.0152,1036.6738 3136.9656,1066.6061 L3173.2391,1121.0285 3183.4602,1145.6061 C3189.0817,1159.1238 3197.1981,1180.7588 3201.4964,1193.6838 3205.7948,1206.6088 3213.755,1229.5588 3219.1857,1244.6838 3228.28,1270.012 3230.3293,1277.2381 3245.1339,1336.1838 L3261.2081,1400.1838 3263.2282,1477.6838 3265.2484,1555.1838 3256.1505,1628.1838 C3251.1467,1668.3338 3244.774,1720.0838 3241.989,1743.1838 3239.204,1766.2838 3234.2421,1806.6396 3230.9627,1832.8633 L3225,1880.5428 3225,1911.9425 3225,1943.3422 3211.5,1995.3895 C3204.075,2024.0156 3197.9986,2048.505 3197.9969,2049.8103 3197.9969,2051.1157 3199.6403,2059.6088 3201.6526,2068.6838 L3205.3114,2085.1838 3215.1899,2102.9116 3225.0683,2120.6395 3229.1672,2140.9116 3233.2662,2161.1838 3231.1672,2234.6838 3229.0683,2308.1838 3225.1775,2323.312 3221.2867,2338.4401 3205.643,2359.9398 C3197.039,2371.7646 3189.437,2381.8712 3188.7497,2382.3989 3187.0602,2383.6959 3131.3777,2399.3921 3106.2316,2405.6596 3086.0774,2410.6829 3051.8924,2416.6838 3043.4304,2416.6838 3039.1744,2416.6838 3039,2416.5657 3039,2413.6838 L3039,2410.6838 2982.4931,2410.6838 C2935.4172,2410.6838 2921.7731,2410.3542 2900.7431,2408.7092 2884.3355,2407.4257 2847.3237,2406.0154 2795,2404.6799 2750.725,2403.5498 2693.8,2401.7708 2668.5,2400.7265 L2622.5,2398.8279 2588,2392.7698 C2558.9562,2387.6698 2546.8082,2386.0769 2511.1868,2382.6978 2456.1533,2377.4771 2450.2886,2377.4835 2404,2382.8146 L2367.5,2387.0183 2329.5,2383.0182 2291.5,2379.0181 2254,2382.8166 C2217.0336,2386.5609 2215.8902,2386.6155 2173.65,2386.6494 L2130.8,2386.6834 2109.7426,2375.1834 C2098.1611,2368.8584 2087.9686,2363.6943 2087.0926,2363.7075 2086.2167,2363.7205 2076.725,2366.4752 2066,2369.8284 2055.275,2373.1816 2045.375,2375.9251 2044,2375.9251 2042.625,2375.9251 2032.725,2373.1816 2022,2369.8284 2011.275,2366.4752 2001.7833,2363.7208 2000.9074,2363.7075 2000.0314,2363.6945 1989.8389,2368.8584 1978.2574,2375.1834 L1957.2,2386.6834 1914.35,2386.6494 C1872.1098,2386.6154 1870.9664,2386.5614 1834,2382.8166 L1796.5,2379.0181 1758.5,2383.0182 1720.5,2387.0183 1684,2382.8146 C1637.7114,2377.4835 1631.8467,2377.4771 1576.8132,2382.6978 1541.1918,2386.0769 1529.0438,2387.6698 1500,2392.7698 L1465.5,2398.8279 1419.5,2400.7265 C1394.2,2401.7708 1337.275,2403.5498 1293,2404.6799 1240.6763,2406.0154 1203.6645,2407.4257 1187.2569,2408.7092 1166.2269,2410.3542 1152.5828,2410.6838 1105.5069,2410.6838 L1048.8655,2410.2806 1049,2413.6838 C1049,2416.6826 1049,2416.6838 1043.25,2416.5689 1040.0875,2416.5059 1029.5807,2415.177 1019.9016,2413.6161 z" 
            Fill="White"   
            Stretch="Uniform"
            Stroke="Blue"
            StrokeThickness="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its not a closed off solid shape.  When adding a drop shadow effect the shadow can be seen inside the lines.  Also I noticed if you remove the stroke property the outline will be red, as is specified in your fill.

Comment: you kind of pointed me in the right direction, so +1. See my answer for the fix.